# Core Data Migration - Remotely

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I’m creating an application that uses Core Data to store information and uses web services to get the data that is needed.

To update Care Data schema, I thought about send the database (with all data) to the server via web service and the server migrate the database and return to the application the new database. With this I’m trying to put the migration process logic on the server. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a really dangerous thing to do because you assume that you a)know exactly what is done to the coredata file (btw, it is not always a database) during a migration b)can anticipate and adapt to any changes Apple might make to the migration process.

It very important when using Core Data to not think of it as a database. It is an object persistence framework that sometimes uses a database for storage.

Comment: My idea is to do all migration process on remote server. The application only cheeks if an update is need and sent the database to the server (the application will block their features while the update is not complete), none of the migration process is done in application. This is an application for "in-house" distribution, and I would like to have control of the migration process, so I can easily control and manipulate the data on the devices.

Comment: Then I would suggest using a database rather than core data. FMDB is a popular SQLite wrapper you might want to check out.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i will have to rethink the migration remotely. If a migration remotely is really necessary, changing to SQLite seems the best option...